# QGIS: Where are these labels saved?

Tags: qgis, labeling

In my QGIS project are 3 labels ("Text", "Turkey", "Syria") displayed (see screenshot) which I can't change or select with the label tools. As you can see on the screenshot, I undisplayed all layers, so, usually nothing should be shown on the map. Where are these labels "saved" and how can I delete them?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like they are [annotations](https://north-road.com/2021/10/21/introducing-annotation-layers-in-qgis-3-22/). Select Modify annotations -  indicated by the red square - in the image below to select the labels and delete them, if you want, using the <kbd>delete</kbd> button on your keyboard.

[image]

Comment: That works. Thanks a lot! Learned that I need to create a annotation layer first to make sure I can display and hide them through the layer panel.